# $ \iint \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dydx $ over a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the following double integral over the region defined by the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$; $(10, 0)$; $(1, 1)$.
>
> $$ \iint \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}dydx $$

I sketched the region, defined the limits of integration of the double integral (two double integrals are required), and when I set out to integrate, I discovered that the function isn't integrable, at least not in rectangular coordinates.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a somewhat easy way for someone without training in real analysis to identify when a function isn't integrable?
2. How can I go about integrating this? Just apply polar coordinates?

Comment: In rectangular coordinates? how?

Comment: You mean after you (partially) integrate over $x$ you obtain an integral in $y$ that can't be solved?

Comment: I can't integrate it at all. I put this integral in SymboLab and it says "no solution".

Comment: $$\iint\sqrt{x^2-y^2}dydx=\left(\int_0^1\int_0^{x}+\int_1^{10}\int_0^{(10-x)/9}\right)\sqrt{x^2-y^2}dydx=\int_0^1\left[\frac12 y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+\frac12x^2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{y=x}+\int_1^{10}\left[\frac12 y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}+\frac12x^2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{y=(10-x)/9}$$